# How to serialize JSON with custom attribute name in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I need to validate the following JSON using Django Rest Framework Serializer:

```
{
  "type": "profit",
  "value": 7200
}
```

My Serializer is defined as:

```
class SaleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        'profit',
        'cost',
    ]
    type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    value = serializers.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(limit_value=10000), MinValueValidator(limit_value=0)], allow_null=False)
```

However, type is one of Python built-in so I don't want to use it for my Serializer. How can I define my serializer so that `type` in the input JSON would be serialized into `sale_type` for example? 
E.g. I would like to defined my serializer as follow:

```
class SaleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        'profit',
        'cost',
    ]
    sale_type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    value = serializers.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(limit_value=10000), MinValueValidator(limit_value=0)], allow_null=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `source` key-word argument for that purpose.

Replace `type = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)` with:

`type = serializers.ChoiceField(source='sale_type', choices=TYPE_CHOICES)`

Comment: This does not change the fact that I still have to use `type` in my serializer.
I've edited my answer so it makes more sense what I wanted.